IBM DB2 iSeries error CWB_MP_TI_EVENT access denied
I'm trying to connect to a DB2 database on AS400 using an alpha version of the .NET core library IBM provides, while my project is written in .NET 8.
Since I have several servers to connect to, they are configured somewhere, and I create a connection string dynamically using the code:
    iDB2ConnectionStringBuilder builder = new()
    {
        DataSource = "[ServerAddress]",
        UserID = "[User]",
        Password = "[Password]",
        PersistSecurityInfo = true
    };

then I use builder.ConnectionString to open the connection.
When I released this code in a production environment, I get the following error:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Alfa.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Trace' threw an exception.
 ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'CWB_MP_TI_EVENT' is denied.
   at System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.CreateEventCore(Boolean initialState, EventResetMode mode, String name, Boolean& createdNew)
   at Alfa.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2NamedEvent..ctor(String eventName)
   at Alfa.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Trace..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Alfa.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Trace.get_Tracing()
   at Alfa.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2ConnectionStringBuilder..ctor()

The exception is thrown by the constructor of iDB2NamedEvent which is called by iDB2Trace which is called by iDB2ConnectionStringBuilder, so apparently none of the code I use to actually open the connection gets called.
I reverse-engineered the dll and found the code of the method where the exception is thrown, which is:
internal iDB2NamedEvent(string eventName)
{
    SecurityPermission securityPermission = new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode);
    waitHandle = null;
    string identity = (new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)) as NTAccount).ToString();
    try
    {
        securityPermission.Assert();
        EventWaitHandleSecurity eventWaitHandleSecurity = new EventWaitHandleSecurity();
        EventWaitHandleAccessRule rule = new EventWaitHandleAccessRule(identity, EventWaitHandleRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
        eventWaitHandleSecurity.AddAccessRule(rule);
        waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(initialState: false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "CWB_MP_TI_EVENT", out var _);
    }
    catch
    {
        CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
        throw;
    }

    CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
}

This code runs in both a windows service, and some ASP.NET web service in the IIS. Now in order to make it work, I have to set in both cases the user they run as to Local System. If I use any different user, I get the error.
Some more info:

I checked the db2 i access client trace tool but the tracing is disabled
The error does not happen in the test server, the same software runs without issues
There is only one software sharing the above code to connect which does not trigger the exception, and it runs in the IIS using ASP NET Core and a library called SoapCore


What exact version of ".NET standard IBM library" are you using?  Ask your i admin to compare the configurations of production environments with non-prod as regards your "different user" group memberships and access-permissions.  There may be additional information on the i diagnostics. Basically, if you have a "working" case (running as 'Local System') and a failing case, it becomes necessary to carefully examine the runtime differences (an i trace will help, as will a  trace of the client-side, but often simply reviewing the security configs, group memberships, permissions/authorities helps

I use an alpha version of the .NET core library IBM provides for connecting to a DB2 database, I should update the question. I don't have an "i admin" as well as any "i diagnostics" or "i trace" tools because I use a very old IBM driver version 7

Anyway I did some changes taking out the iDB2ConnectionStringBuilder and the rest of the connection logic and bringing it to a non-async method, it seems to have fixed the issue in the web service inside the IIS, but I still have to do more test

I can confirm that the issue still persists

The symptom will persist until root cause is established and addressed. What is the VRM shown in the output of the DSPPTF command on the as400 (ask the administrator of the as400 to help with this) ?

. If the symptom has a client-side only cause, then you need to grant read/write/full permissions for the chosen user to the directories/files used by your Db2-client. Use the Microsoft tool procmon/procmon64 (download from microsoft.com only) to examine file open failures. If your Db2 driver is from the i access solution (i.e not clidriver), its tracing might default to c:\cotrcs but procmon/procmon64 will show the real paths/files.

I understand that your application can't works using an account different of Local System. And the exception you have post (Access to the path 'CWB_MP_TI_EVENT' is denied.) confirm that this is a local permission config problem to the trace file.
Can you have a look at the iDB2ConnectionStringBuilder and check if you have a Trace param ? Something like TraceFile or EnableTrace that you can disable ? My projects uses the .Net Core 3.1 packages and I don't have this object. If you have TraceFile try to point to a file where the current user has access.
[Edit] Did you previously enabled tracing using cwbmptrc described here : https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/tracing-and-diagnostics-net-provider ?
My code sample in .Net6 to use a tracefile in the temp folder :
using IBM.Data.Db2;
using IBM.EntityFrameworkCore;

var csBuilder = new DB2ConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Server = "",
    Database = "",
    UserID = "",
    Password = "",
    SchemaList = "",
    traceFile = Path.GetTempPath() + "Db2Trace.txt"
};

var connectionString = csBuilder.ToString();

builder.UseDb2(connectionString, optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.SetServerInfo(IBMDBServerType.AS400, IBMDBServerVersion.AS400_07_02));


I do have a trace param but I was not able to figure out where it is pointing, do you have any ideas?

I was talking more about traceFile. I've edited my answer

I checked the builder object but I only have a Trace property of type iDB2TraceOptions (enum), with values Default, DatabaseMonitor, StartDebug, PrintJoblog, TraceJob, TraceDatabaseServer. The default value is Default but I have no idea whether a trace file is created or where it might be

@Phate01 Did you use Microsoft procmon64 to filter for file open errors while your program is running?  This gives definitive information. Use it.

@mao I tried but I saw nothing useful, although I have no experience with this tool. Can you contact me provately? I shared my github and there you will find my email

@Phate01 I don't know how to contact you.  In procmon, BEFORE runnning your program, add filters to limit output. e.g , Result "is not" Success, Operation "ends with" File, and maybe (if not too restrictive) ProcessName "is" (your exe file).   Note my other remark re c:\cotrcs. Study "Path" column in resulting output.

The code
internal iDB2NamedEvent(string eventName)
{
    SecurityPermission securityPermission = new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode);
    waitHandle = null;
    string identity = (new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)) as NTAccount).ToString();
    try
    {
        securityPermission.Assert();
        EventWaitHandleSecurity eventWaitHandleSecurity = new EventWaitHandleSecurity();
        EventWaitHandleAccessRule rule = new EventWaitHandleAccessRule(identity, EventWaitHandleRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
        eventWaitHandleSecurity.AddAccessRule(rule);
        waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(initialState: false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "CWB_MP_TI_EVENT", out var _);
    }
    catch
    {
        CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
        throw;
    }

    CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
}

is wrong. It creates a named Event but does not attach the security permissions to it. I guess they were asking ChatGPT ... This is how the code should look like:
        bool wasCreated = false;

        var ewh = new EventWaitHandle(false,
            EventResetMode.ManualReset,
            "CWB_MP_TI_EVENT",
            out wasCreated);

        if( wasCreated )
        {
            var users = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
            var rule = new EventWaitHandleAccessRule(users, EventWaitHandleRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
            var security = new EventWaitHandleSecurity();
            security.AddAccessRule(rule);

            ewh.SetAccessControl(security);
        }

Get an updated driver from your IBM guy. In the meantime, you can create a fixer application which tries to open the existing object and sets the permissions to the settings you need. This fix application would need to run as System to be able to do this.

The root cause of the error lies in the permission constraints associated with creating or accessing a named event. The CWB_MP_TI_EVENT, in particular, is subject to a security policy that mandates elevated privileges. When the application runs under a user context that differs from Local System, it's probable that the necessary permissions are not present, thereby triggering the UnauthorizedAccessException.
1. Ensure the User Account Has Necessary Permissions
To resolve this, you can either:
Give the user account running the service the necessary permissions so it can work properly:

Ensure the user has the required permissions to create and manage
event handles. This typically involves granting the user account the
SeCreateGlobalPrivilege and potentially SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege
privileges.

2. Modify the Security Settings in Code
If you have control over the code, you can modify the security settings programmatically to grant the appropriate access to the event handle. Here’s an example of how to modify the iDB2NamedEvent method to ensure that the event handle is created with the appropriate security settings:
 internal iDB2NamedEvent(string eventName)
{
    SecurityPermission securityPermission = new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode);
    waitHandle = null;
    string identity = (new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)) as NTAccount).ToString();
    try
    {
        securityPermission.Assert();
        EventWaitHandleSecurity eventWaitHandleSecurity = new EventWaitHandleSecurity();
        EventWaitHandleAccessRule rule = new EventWaitHandleAccessRule(identity, EventWaitHandleRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
        eventWaitHandleSecurity.AddAccessRule(rule);
        
        bool createdNew;
        waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(initialState: false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "CWB_MP_TI_EVENT", out createdNew, eventWaitHandleSecurity);
    }
    catch
    {
        CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
        throw;
    }

    CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
}

3. Using App Pool Identity in IIS
For IIS, ensure the application pool identity has the necessary permissions:

Open IIS Manager.

Select the Application Pool running your ASP.NET application.

Click "Advanced Settings...".

Under "Process Model", change the "Identity" to an account that has the required permissions or configure it to use a custom account that you ensure has those permissions.


4. Running as Local System
As a last resort, you can continue running the services under the Local System account if changing permissions is not viable. However, running services under Local System is generally not recommended for security reasons unless absolutely necessary.
let me know if you still gets any error.

I can't modify the class iDB2NamedEvent directly because it is in a library, can you give me some more info about the user privileges and how to set em?
